# Need ffmpegsumo.dll from a very specific Chrome version

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

For an nw.js (formerly known as node-webkit) app, I need `ffmpegsumo.dll` from a very specific version of Google Chrome, 41.0.2272.76 (win32 & 64), as described in [the nw.js documentation](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Using-MP3-&-MP4-%28H.264%29-using-the--video--&--audio--tags.).

I can't find a download for this specific version of Chrome anywhere. Doesn't Google keep a public archive?

Where can I get Chrome 41.0.2272.76 or just its `ffmpegsumo.dll`?

<sub>...apart from building it myself.</sub>

Comment: In the meantime the actual problem was fixed, because the dll from a slightly newer version works fine. But that's temporary, in the future that version may become unavailable as well.

Comment: Maybe you still have URL where from I can download ffmpegsumo for that version ?